# How to add data to an existing power pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

I'm looking for a way to load more recent data as date x in Power Pivot and link/add them to an existing table.

Background:

The user downloads data from a datafeed and saves them in Excel Power Pivot.
The data will be deleted from the server afterwards.
In the next step, new data must be added to the existing table in Power Pivot, 
so that the workbook graphics can access the complete dataset.

I know there is no API for VBA access to Power Pivot. Is there a
workaround with linked tables and direct access to the database?

Answer (score 0):

1) you create one table just containing the dates from earliest to far into the future

2) you import every new set of data into a new power pivot table

3) you link the dates for a record in the newly imported table to the dates in the power pivot table containing the dates

so the backbone of your whole data is the dates table, while your tables keeping the actual data are treated as lookup tables.

this is hacky and I didn't try it, but it should work